# JavaScript createElement("h4") parses, creates text node, but doesn't create H4 element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a `for` loop create H4 tags containing text, followed by some paragraph text, then repeat.
Here's what I've done:

```
var results = document.getElementById("results"); //refers to a <p> in html file
var stopper = 29;

for(i=0; i <= stopper; i++) {
    var elementDate = document.createElement("h4");
    elementDate.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Text gathered from an array"));
    results.appendChild(elementDate);
    results.innerText += "Paragraph text";
}
```

I also tried `elementDate.innerText = "..."` but I'm getting the same problem:

Instead of creating an H4 and appending the text, it just appends the text straight to `<p id="results">`. The H4 is never created and there are no errors in the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
results.innerText += "Paragraph text";
```

What this does is:

- Extracts the current `innerText` of the element, resulting in a *plain string* (no HTML tags)
- Concatenates `"Paragraph text"` onto the end of that string
- Sets that new string to be the new `innerText` of the element (no HTML tags)

So, the `<h4>` gets lost. (`innerText` should [not be used](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) in almost all situations anyway)

Use `insertAdjacentText` instead:

```js
var results = document.getElementById("results"); //refers to a <p> in html file
var stopper = 29;

for(i=0; i <= stopper; i++) {
    var elementDate = document.createElement("h4");
    elementDate.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Some text which would be gathered from an array"));
    results.appendChild(elementDate);
    results.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', "Paragraph text");
}
```

```html
<p id="results"></p>
```

(You might be tempted to do `.innerHTML +=`, but that would allow for arbitrary code execution, in addition to corrupting existing nodes in the container, which would be inelegant and would effectively deattach any event listeners attached to them)

Comment: This is nicer than what was going to post, which was to create a text node and append it.

Comment: As for closing remark on `innerHTML`, I would suggest to go [even further](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText) and use `.textContent` instead

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yep, that doesn't allow for arbitrary code execution, but it *would* corrupt the existing `<h4>` node you just created, replacing it with a new one (and thereby destroying any listeners one might have tried to add to it)

Comment: Beautiful, can't believe I'd never been taught about this. It does seem to create a new problem in that it eliminates my `\n` characters that I'd like to insert after each text node. Do you know of a way to insert line breaks with this method?